# The torus as a complex variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm interested in the topological torus, ie. the homeomorphism class of $S^1\times S^1$.

Clearly, it can be realized as the real algebraic variety in $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the solution set to $x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1$, $x_3^2+x_4^2=1$.

Now I wonder, is there a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2: p(x,y)=0\}$ is homeomorphic to the torus?

(I'd be fine with more equations in some higher-dimensional space, but one equation in $\mathbb{C}^2$ would clearly be best.)

A much more general question, which I'd be happy to get some info on but is not required for accepting the answer, is, how would I go about determining the homeomorphism type of given (complex or real) variety (say given in terms of reasonable polynomial equations in not too many variables)?

Comment: finding the homeomorphism class of a variety (or of any space) is hard. On the other hand, thanks to the Weil conjectures, there is an algorithm that will tell you the Betti numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The zero set of a polynomial $p\in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ is unbounded (FTA), but the torus is compact, so that doesn't work.

OTOH you can get many toruses as algebraic varieties in the projective space $\Bbb{C}P^2$. Look up *Elliptic curves*. These can also be described as sets of solutions of an equation of the form
$$
y^2=x^3+Ax+B
$$
together with a point at infinity. Here $A,B$ can be any constants such that the polynomial on the r.h.s. has no multiple zeros. Including the point at infinity also serves as a one-point compactification.